# Как сделать div'ы в двух соседних колонках одинаковыми по высоте?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Имеется адаптивная таблица на Bootstrap:

```
<section class="print-block__table">
  <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-5 offset-lg-1 pr-lg-0">
            <div class="table__header">Плюсы</div>
            <div class="table__content">печать неощутима на ткани</div>
            <div class="table__content">футболку можно гладить по рисунку</div>
            <div class="table__content">высокая стойкость рисунка при стирке</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5 pl-lg-0">
             <div class="table__header">Минусы</div>
             <div class="table__content">самый сложный и поэтому дорогой способ шелкографии</div>
             <div class="table__content">технологически сложно достичь точной цветопередачи, некоторые цвета не выглядят так ярко, как задумывалось в макете</div>
             <div class="table__content">возможный процент брака больше, чем при других видах шелкографии, так как результат можно увидеть только после сушки</div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Как сделать строки в левой колонке аналогичными по высоте строкам правой колонки?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/sasha_jarvi/pen/jgOBwm

Comment: При сохранении текущей разметки - никак, разве что на `js`

Comment: Ограничивайте высоту строк или как вы себе это представляете, если у вас разное количество контента в строках, который и влияет на высоту.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_equal_height.asp

Answer (score 0):

Йоу! У тебя трабл в том, что у строк, ну или же table_content, разные размеры высоты, а тебе надо сделать так, чтобы они были одинаковые. Значит тебе надо поменять их высоту на одну, фиксированную. То-есть можно просто добавить в table_content высоту, height.
Вот пример:

```css
    .table__header,
    .table__content {
      padding: 1.25rem 0;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #484848;
      vertical-align: middle;
      border-top: none;
      height: 60px; // это то, чу я добавил
    }
```